# How to clear radio buttons / clear all selected radio buttons to false state. reactjs - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap4-modal

How can I reset radio button to default state or clear all selected radio buttons.
[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-easryi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your `onReset` method in this way to clear (or reset) all selected radio buttons in your form:

```
onReset = () => {
  // Extract out cards from your state
  var cards = this.state.cards

  // Iterate each card..
  cards.forEach(card => {

    // Iterate each card option..
    card.options.forEach(option => {

      // Reset selected value of option
      option.selected = false
    })
  })

  // Apply "reset" card state to your component to cause a re-render
  this.setState({ cards : cards })
}
```

Here is a running sample for you to see in action:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ujmlcz?file=index.js

Comment: Hey budy. Can u help me with this problem please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157601/react-onclick-lisitem-display-the-data-of-selected-lisitem-from-json). Trying to fetch selected data onclick listitem  but it is fetching all the data.

Comment: @contactdummy yes, I've just provided you an answer - hope that helps