# React onClick listItem display the data of selected listItem from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am new to coding world. Learning react and json. I am working on three different panels which are linked together. I want to display checklist answer on the third panels.

**First panel:** 

Display: all the esn ("4667","4668")
onclick on first esn:"4667" it should display all the gmtdatetime of esn:"4667" on the second panel. 

**Second panel:**

Displaying: All the gmtdatetime of esn:"4667" ('2018-08-31 03:22:16','2018-08-30 03:12:16') 
onclick on the first gmtdatetime '2018-08-31 03:22:16' it should show question + answers on the third panel of that gmtdatetime '2018-08-31 03:22:16'.

**Third panel:**

It should display all the value (question +answer) of the first gmtdatetime in this format. I want to display yes or not rather than true or false. 
Question  answer 
question 1  true == "YES" 
question 2  true == "YES" 
question 3  false == "NO" 
question 4  true == "YES"

**Original code: [react-editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzhjha)**

**Output**

```
  onClick on ESN ("4667") =>
                          onClick Date & Time ("2018-08-31 03:22:16") =>  
                                               Checklist (Question + Answer)
                                              "question 1"  true == "YES"
                                              "question 2"  true == "YES"
                                              "question 3"  false == "NO"
                                              "question 4"  true == "NO"
```

My json data looks like this 
 [image: Json view]

```
    [
    {
        esn: '4667',
        completed_checklists: [
            {
                gmtdatetime: '2018-08-31 03:22:16',
                answers: ['true','true','false','true']
            },
            {
                gmtdatetime: '2018-08-30 03:12:16',
                answers: ['false','true','true','true']
            }
        ],
        question: ['question 1','question 2','question 3','question 4']
    },
    {
        esn: '4668',
        completed_checklists: [
            {
                gmtdatetime: '2017-08-31 03:22:16',
                answers: ['true','false','false','true']
            },
            {
                gmtdatetime: '2017-08-31 03:23:16',
                answers: ['true','false','false','true']
            }
        ],
        question: ['question 1','question 2','question 3','question 4']

    },

]
```

**Issue**
fetching all the data on the second panel and the third panel.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there I have fork your code, I think this is what you are after [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvtbun?file=index.js)

Comment: Thank u so much. I have one question regarding the answer. How can I change display True == "YES" False == "NO". I want to display yes and no rather than true or false

Comment: @contactdummy see answer below

Comment: @GuillermoQuiros you're in Wellington still? Nice!

Comment: Yes I am, raining and raining :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows a completed solution, with `true == YES` and `false == NO`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wej2w1

Comment: Thank u but  i want output something like this `onClick on ESN ("4667") =>
                          onClick Date & Time ("2018-08-31 03:22:16") =>  
                                               Checklist (Question + Answer)
                                              "question 1"  true == "YES"
                                              "question 2"  true == "YES"
                                              "question 3"  false == "NO"
                                              "question 4"  true == "NO"'`

Comment: Guillermo code is working perfect only how to change the true to yes and false to no..

Comment: Hi  @contactdummy , see the updated link in my answer

Comment: I agree - it would be very useful. I will try and find time :-)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637614/filter-react-table-and-react-leaflet-marker-at-the-same-time-using-textfield-sh?noredirect=1#comment92208389_52637614) can you help me with this one. It's react-leaflet.